# OnClick in an angular-openlayers-directive marker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, openlayers-3

Thats it I want to create an onclick event on my marker, I'm using angular-openlayers-directive.

So far I've been able to make some markers show up, but I'm unable to get them after a click event.

I would like to perform some actions with these markers custom properties like name, remarks, etc. But it seems too hard to achieve this with openlayers 3.

```
 <openlayers ol-center="ven" height="100vh">
    <ol-layer ol-layer-properties="wms">
      <ol-marker ng-repeat="marker in markers"
                 lat="marker.lat"
                 lon="marker.lon"
        ></ol-marker>
    </ol-layer>
  </openlayers>
```

So how could I handle an onclick event on these markers and get all their info, or a reference to the javascript object "marker" itself.

Answer (score 4):

I wasn't sure if you wanted to have the click on the popover or the marker itself.  Below there are instructions for both.  Use the Plunker link at the bottom to see a working demo of both options.

### To Register Click on Marker Popover:

If you take a look at the directive, you can see that the marker template uses ng-transclude, so you can do the following:

**Markup:**

```
<ol-marker ol-marker-properties="santiago" >
  <p ng-click="showDetails(santiago)">Santiago de Compostela</p>
</ol-marker>
```

**In your controller:**

```
$scope.showDetails = function(id) {
  alert('lat: '+ id.lat+', '+'lon: '+id.lon);
};
```

Here I'm passing in the marker object to the showDetails function.  When you click the popover label for **Santiago de Compostela** in the Plunker Demo, you'll see the corresponding lat/lon in the alert.

### To Register Click on the Marker:

You can add an onClick property to the marker object as follows:

**In your controller:**

```
finisterre: {
  lat: 42.907800500000000000,
  lon: -9.265031499999964000,
  label: {
    show: false,
  },
  onClick: function (event, properties) {
    console.log(properties); 
    alert('lat: '+ properties.lat+', '+'lon: '+properties.lon);
  }
}
```

When you click the marker associated with **finisterre** in the Plunker Demo, you'll see the corresponding lat/lon in the alert.

**NOTE:**
I could only get this to work though under the following conditions:

1. The marker object must have a label property defined
2. The show property of the label must be set to false.
3. The ol-marker html element must have some transcluded content *OR* the message property must be set in the marker label object.

I was able to use CSS to prevent the popover from displaying as you can see in the demo, but it seems a little hacky.  If you want the popover to display on click as well, you're all set, just remove the css `hidden` class I added and add your pop-over html.

## [Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/1xu7QBZlemqREmybrGHZ?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I just got this working today as it happens. What I am doing for now is adding the properties to my markers once I get them from mongo.

```
function addMarkerProperties ()
// needed to enable click events on a marker!
// Have a label property defined for the marker.
// Have the show property of the label set to false.
// Have some transcluded content in the marker.
{
  for (var i = $scope.markers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    $scope.markers[i].onClick = function (event, properties) { console.log('Clicked a marker'); console.log(this); console.log(properties); };
    $scope.markers[i].label = { 
    // Note: Duplication of data here @ message. Fix this later.
    "message": $scope.markers[i].name,
  "show": false,
  "showOnMouseOver": false
  };
  };
}
```

Once the markers have all the properties they need. It just sort of works but I do have a bug to iron out as well where the marker titles repeat above the map for.... reasons. [image: Openlayers Weirdness]
As you click the markers the words disappear.

Comment: I had that error the reason was missing CSS that hides those titles

Answer (score 0):

With the latest release (April 6 2016) of the *angular-openlayers-directive* library (correct) *ngClick*-handling seems to be implemented. After a bit of searching I came up with the following solution:

The HTML (simplified):

```
<html ng-controller="mapController">
    <openlayers width="100%" height="400px">
        <ol-marker ng-repeat="marker in markers" ol-marker-properties="marker" ng-click="showDetails(marker)"></ol-marker>
    </openlayers>
</html>
```

The Angular Javascript for the map controller (expects that your API endpoint called '/api/markerlist' returns a list of JSON objects with the fields: 'latitude', 'longitude'):

```
$scope.markers = [];

$scope.initializeMarkers = function() {    
var markerList = $http.get("yoursite/api/markerlist")
.succes( function(result) {    
 angular.forEach(result, function(value, key) {
                        $scope.markers.push({
                            lat: value.latitude,
                            lon: value.longitude,
                            label: {
                                message: "Your message",
                                show: false,
                                showOnMouseOver: false
                            }
                        });
                });

}

function showDetails(marker) {
    alert('Clicked a marker on the map');
    console.log(marker);
}
```

Finally, be sure that you have included the *angular-openlayer-directive* CSS, so the messages for the labels are not visible.